# Tip box for Story ID questions

Tags: feature-request, tags, story-identification, questions, tag-tips

Editing a question on Movies & TV.SE, which was tagged [identify-this-movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-movie) (their equivalent of [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification), I saw this awesome little reminder box pop up automatically, reminding OPs to include relevant information:

[image]

It asks for language, country of origin, and approximate year of release.

We frequently find ourselves leaving comments on Story ID questions here on SF&F, asking the OP about format, book cover designs, approximate time the OP read/watched the media in question, etc.

### Shouldn't we save ourselves some hassle by adopting a similar tip box for all questions tagged [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification)?

If M&TV did it, it should be relatively easy to follow suit.

SO has a similar feature:

[image]

Comment: I'd like this suggestion approximately a hundred billion percent more if the tip box could automatically suggest the story-id tag itself. Unfortunately I think the level of AI required is *slightly* beyond SO's resources right now

Comment: @JasonBaker -  There's an argument to be made that new users frequently ask a story ID question first, and as such, we should have some text appear under the tag bar asking "Are you trying to identify a story?  Click here" by default for new users.  But alas, that is a suggestion for another meta question.

Comment: Related meta question that sparked the referenced implementation (and has links to the SO precedent without which it would probably not have been feasible at all): http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1419/49

Comment: Note however, that M&TV's implementation is by far not perfect, it isn't configurable at all without involvement of SE übermods and it only shows when the tag edit box looses focus (which often happens right when clicking "Post Your Question"). And as Jason remarks, it of course requires the correct tag in the first place, but that is likely not circumventable.

Comment: @TARS - Imperfect is far preferable to what we have now (i.e., nothing).

Comment: @WadCheber Well, you also aren't literally *plagued* by those question, so I wouldn't say it's that urgent. But sure, it's a nice thing.

Comment: @TARS - I actually can't tell if you were being facetious.  Story ID is by far our most commonly used tag, twice as common as the #2 tag.  We tend to get decent Story ID questions, and I understand that's not really true of M&TV's ID questions, but we certainly get a crap ton of them.  More than twice as many as M&TV, in fact (5286 vs. 2402).  But of course, we have more questions overall than M&TV, for reasons I don't fully understand.

Comment: @WadCheber Well, at least not facetious regarding the fact that M&TV indeed seems to be plagued by those questions while this site doesn't seem to. If I have overestimated the quality or underestimated the amount of ID questions on this site here, then I might simply be wrong with that above statement, but that was then rather unintentional.

Comment: @TARS - No, we have often discussed in chat the peculiar fact that other SE sites have problems with low quality ID questions, but ours are almost always decent or at least salvageable.  The best theory (in my opinion) for explaining it is that the things people usually remember about a sci fi story are also the things that make the story unique and memorable.  That makes it easier to identify such stories.  The same dynamic doesn't necessarily apply to movies and television shows, or whatever else.

Comment: @TARS - So we get more ID questions than you, but they are usually better (i.e., easier to answer) than the ones you get, and because we have more questions overall than you, our story ID questions make up a smaller percentage of our questions than is the case on M&TV.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought that "the things people usually remember about a . . . story are also the things that make the story . . . memorable" is peculiar to sci-fi stories.

Comment: @user14111 - The conceits are.  A wizard who has to destroy a ring, a boy trying to redeem his father who has become a monstrous henchman to an evil Emperor, etc.  Compared to other kinds of stories, the details of sci fi are unique to a degree even when they bear similarities to other works.  Being memorable to me doesn't always mean it's memorable to you, but "father son laser sword fight" is pretty easy to identify.  You deliberately omitted my use of the words "unique and" before "memorable" because you wanted to play gotcha. That means you understand the point.

Comment: @user14111 - In any case, not my idea, I'm just paraphrasing it.  http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7116/44025

Comment: No, I didn't get your point till later. I'm not that smart. I'm so dumb that when I saw the title of your question, I thought a "tip box" would be an arrangement where the guy whose story ID question gets answered can donate a dollar to the guy who answered it.

Comment: @TARS You might find [this interesting](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7509/31051) (inspired by Napoleon's very similar post on M&TV Meta)

Comment: They were called "tag warnings" when Ask Ubuntu was asked about them: http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14237/158442

Comment: The [tag:fantasy-genre] and [tag:science-fiction-genre] tags are often used (wrongly) in place of the story ID tag. Between the genre tags and story ID, I reckon we could hoover up most of the story ID questions as they're asked.

Comment: Note that Shog9 posted a comment on [Meta.SF saying this was "trivial to implement"](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8054/abrupt-change-in-moderation-staff#comment17371_8054); so if we can agree on what to put in them (and if we think it's a good idea, which we seem to), we shouldn't have a problem getting them

Answer (score 11):

**Yes, we should implement this.**

The specific contents can be decided on in a separate question, but this would help. If nothing else, it would help establish guidelines for asking story ID questions.

Also, if tip boxes can be added to be shown by all tags, we could add one that instructs users to add [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) if they have a story ID question, if that tag isn't already on the question.

---

*Perhaps the larger franchises could benefit from tip boxes as well, instructing people to use both the main franchise tag and the specific work tag (for instance [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek) and [star-trek-tos](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-tos)), or other pointers for that franchise, but again, that's something for another question.*

Comment: You may want to note that having this box doesn't seem to have helped the mod team on Movies.SE achieve what they consider an acceptable level of quality on Story-ID questions.

Comment: @Valorum True, but it doesn't hurt to try. Like I said, it will at least establish guidelines for Story ID questions.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced that we have a big enough problem to merit doing something about it.

Comment: I believe that our [tag:story-identification] questions are of a consistently high quality compared to many other sites. I doubt this will increase the quality much, but it might save me and others a lot of comments asking people to add pertinent details. So, +1.

Comment: I'm with @Valorum here. We don't have that much of a quality problem in story-ID questions (especially compared to other sites), and adding a tip box probably wouldn't do much to fix it. Adding the occasional comment to ask for more detail isn't too much hassle, especially now that we have [this thread](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question?noredirect=1&lq=1) to help with crafting those comments.